# Ensuring AdornmentDecorator within a ContentPresenter, but without a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, contentpresenter, errortemplate

I've searched around quite a bit and can't seem to crack this nut.

I've got an app with a main view that changes dynamically, and to do this I use content presenter with a binding to a control:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" x:Name="StepScrollViewer">
        <StackPanel Margin="20,20,20,500">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainControl}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Then I change the MainControl at runtime in my view model.  The problem is that the controls getting bound don't reliably display their error templates... I suspect it is for the reasons discussed here:

[Validation ErrorTemplate not showing on data errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676266/validation-errortemplate-not-showing-on-data-errors)

But the fix for this problem doesn't seem to work for me because I'm not using a control template around my content presenter.  When I wrap an AdornmentDecorator tag around my content presenter, it doesn't seem to fix the problem.  It DOES work if I put an AdornmentDecorator inside each control I load into the contentpresenter (as the root element), but I'd like to avoid this repetition if possible.

Any insights?

UPDATE

I tried this approach suggested by Dennis, but to no avail.  The control binds okay, but it works no better than the current approach (also shown commented below). Note: I tried it both with the AdornerDecorator as a singleton element the way Dennis has it, and surrounding the ContentPresenter, as shown below.  Neither show any difference - the adorners around my controls all disappear when the MainControl binding is changed.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MainContentControl" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainControl}"/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>

     .....


    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" x:Name="StepScrollViewer">
        <StackPanel Margin="20,20,20,500" >
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MainContentControl}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <!-- THE BELOW WORKS IF I SURROUND EACH BOUND CONTROL WITH adornerdecorator -->
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" x:Name="StepScrollViewer">
        <StackPanel Margin="20,20,20,500">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainControl}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `ContentPresenter` directly, I would instead use a `ContentControl`. A `ContentControl` is the base class for controls that contain other elements and have a `Content` property, e.g. `Button`.

Then you can override the template to have an `AdornerDecorator` next to the `ContentControl`. This is different to what you previously tried as now the `ContentPresenter` is part of the same visual tree as the `Adorner`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </AdornerDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*Edit: Forgot that the `AdornerDecorator` needs to wrap the container, not just sit side-by-side.*

Comment: If this doesn't work; let me know and I will help further. It has been a while since I've done anything with WPF.

Comment: I guess I need the other piece of XAML that goes with this... I can put that style in my resources (I hate WPF for calling such a clearly functional thing a "style", but that is off-topic), but how do I "apply" the style to a Scroll panel or a... Well, what would I apply it to?  And how would I then bind that dynamically to a control MVVM style?

Comment: Well, the above doesn't technically work the way I wanted it to.  I still need to actually put an AdornerDecorator element around the body of each user control that is loaded into the content presenter.  For now, I guess that's what I'll do.